# why do Thread.interrupt() throw IllegalThreadStateException?

Tags: android, blackberry

Please explain to me why do the following code throw IllegalThreadStateException?

```
try
{
    if(thread1 != null)
    {
        if(thread1.isAlive()); 
        {
            thread1.interrupt();   //it is ok
            thread1.join();
        }
    }
    if(thread2 != null)
    {
        if(thread2.isAlive());
        {
            thread2.interrupt(); //throw IllegalThreadStateException
            thread2.join();
        }
    }
}
catch(IllegalThreadStateException e)
{
    System.exit(0);
}
```

It threw IllegalThreadStateException when run statement thread2.interrupt(). But thread1.interrupt() is ok.

Please explain to me.

Many thanks!

Comment: What's the exception message?

Comment: The message from e.toString() is only "java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException"

Comment: `e.toString()` is not the message.  Check `getMessage()` or `printStackTrace()`.

Comment: This is inherently unsafe, because the thread might finish just after the `if` check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line:

```
if(thread2.isAlive()); // <-- Note this semicolon well!
```

is not doing what you think it's doing :-) The code segment:

```
if(thread2.isAlive());
{
    thread2.interrupt(); //throw IllegalThreadStateException
    thread2.join();
}
```

will check if the thread is alive and, if so, execute that empty statement before the semicolon. It will then execute the `interrupt/join` sequence inside the braces *no matter what* the state of the thread was. That's because:

```
{
    doSomething();
}
```

is a perfectly valid Java construct, even without an `if` or `while` preceding it. Change:

```
if(thread2.isAlive());
```

to:

```
if(thread2.isAlive())
```

(and do the same for the `thread1` check as well).

---

And you should also call `getMessage()` on the exception to find out the specific details, if any.

It may contain extra information for easier root cause analysis.

Comment: This is 100% true, but it won't help.

Comment: Can we assume from your comment, @Levanphong7887, that the problem was as we thought? You should go back over your old answers and start accepting those that best answered your questions. You'll likely get more responses to future questions that way.

Comment: Based on the Javadocs, @SLaks, you may well have been right. But I'd prefer to get rid of the obvious problems first, especially since "living" is a state and the exception was quite adamant about the state being invalid in this case.

Comment: Note that this doesn't help much, since the thread might finish just after the `if` check.